# Does the Arduino Wifi Shield (antenna connector) require an external antenna to work?

Tags: arduino

I found 2 versions of the Arduino Wifi Shield on the Arduino website.

- Arduino Wifi Shield (antenna connector) http://store.arduino.cc/ww/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11_5&products_id=312
- Arduino WiFi Shield (integrated antenna) http://store.arduino.cc/ww/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11_5&products_id=237

If I buy Arduino Wifi Shield (antenna connector), will I need to buy an external antenna to make it work?

Comment: Why not simply contact them? http://store.arduino.cc/eu/index.php?main_page=contact_us

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to buy and attach the external antenna.  You would have many choices for antennas.

The integrated version should be fine if you are in an environment with good signal and the arduino is not inside a metal box.

You go to the trouble of the external antenna:

- if you need better signal, for example to communicate longer distance from access point
- if you want to package the Arduino inside a metal box, you would use the external antenna on the outside of the box.